# Composition of arcanite (potassium sulfate) agricultural grade. Potassium content of random drawn sample?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I bought potassium sulfate from this source:

[Potassium sulfate granulate](https://agrarshop.ch/duenger/duenger-fuer-landwirtschaft-und-gartenbau/k-duenger/12/kalisulfat-kalisop-granuliert-1050kg-42-saecke-a-25kg-im-bio-landbau-zugelassen)

I'm using it as a potassium additive in hydroponics. The composition is listed as K2O = 50%, S = 18%. This equals about 41.5% K (50* (mass of K / mass of K2O) Calculated from mass percentages (mass of K2 / K2SO4) potassium sulfate should contain about 44.9% K and and 18% S. So based on this calculations I concluded that the potassium content is within the margin of error tolerable for fertilizer application. (About 3.4% for potassium)

However after further reading I came across an article which suggested that raw materials should be as homogeneous as possible because otherwise a sample drawn randomly could have huge variations in the content of the chemicals involved. How high could the deviation be with respect to potassium?f I think the source material is arcanite

EDIT: The security data sheet states that the purity of the granulate is guaranteed to be between 90-99%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deviation can be in range from negligible to huge, depending on the level of nonhomogeneity and locality of the sample.

Note that routine analysis of potentially non-homogenous sources involve sophisticated sampling and sample averaging schema, so the result is representing number.

Comment: I have found the security data sheet and it states that the purity is between 90-99%. How can the variation be huge, when it is a nearly pure substance? Couldn't the variation then be 10% at max?

Comment: There can be time variation between lots, based on variability of used raws.

Comment: So basically I should look for the maximal variability of K2SO4 in arcanite by a literature review?

Comment: The point is, it may not be the pure mineral of whatever internal purity, but minor external impurities may be present in variable amount. It is fertilizer, after all, not substance of a lab purity.

Comment: If I assumed its purity to be 100%. Then dosing the nutrient solution according to this value. The content of potassium & sulfur can then only be lower but not higher. Is this reasoning correct? I don't mind lower values but higher can be detrimental.

Comment: K2SO4 cannot contain more than 100% of itself. But if there is present other compound with higher percentage of potassium, like KCl, then effective K2O content CAN be higher than of 100% K2SO4.

Comment: It also states that the max. concentration of chlorine is 1%. Based on your objections of variation between lots the chlorine content could also be higher for some lots but is only on average 1%. Or does this only apply to the main ingredients? (Like K or S?)

Comment: Chlorine is kind of guaranteed to be below 1%. So you can count with max K2O content as if it was pure K2SO4.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot with your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

The picture of the product (2-4 mm granules) on the website looks very homogeneous.

[image]

If you consider the product acceptable, except for possible inhomogeneity, you could examine smaller samples or homogenize larger portions. Dissolving in water seems the easiest way, and could provide a further check on purity/homogeneity. $K_2SO_4$ is soluble in water about 10% by weight. For a small scale test, dissolve a 100 gram sample of your Kalisop in 1 liter of warm (or hot) water and stir to complete dissolution. The specification says “vollständig wasserlöslich” - completely water soluble. If a small amount doesn’t dissolve, you could filter it off and weigh it. Check as many samples as you need to to assure yourself of homogeneity or consistency of the material. Also check pH.

Agrarshop specifies 1% as a chloride maximum: “ Praktisch chloridfrei”; this comes out to about 2.1% (max) impurity if $KCl$. Any precipitate could be a calcium sulfate.

If you are satisfied with the product but want to go the extra mile, you could homogenize 1 kg in 10 liters of water in a 20 liter bucket. Or scale up even further, especially if the product is indeed, completely water soluble.

The source of the $K_2SO_4$ could be arcanite mineral but that is relatively rare. On the other hand, 1.5 million tons of potassium sulfate was made in 1985, typically by the reaction: $ KCl  + H_2SO_4$ —> $HCl + KHSO_4$, followed by heating: $ KCl + KHSO_4$ → $HCl + K_2SO_4$. The cost of Kalisop is about 1.36 US dollars per kg, which could support a large-scale manufacturing process, but it also depends on the cost of $KCl$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I dissolved it and found only very little impurities, looked like sand. That's why I assumed it is arcanite, but could obviously just be impurities from manufacturing / storage..Do you know if dissolved K2SO4 expires?

Comment: K2SO4 in water has no chemical reactions available. However, dilute solutions might support biological growths and get cloudy or clotty. Still good enough for plants that are already growing in dirt. The clots might fowl up a delicate pump, but the chemicals will be stable.